# Why is logger.setLevel() in Snowflake not working?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've got a requirement to write logging data from our Snowflake Stored Procedures written in Snowpark to a table in Snowflake. To do this, I've written a Python logger handler that writes logging information to a table, and set up a get_logger function that will return a logger with this handler:

```py
def get_logger(name: str, log_table_name: str, snowflake_session, level: int = logging.INFO) -> logging.Logger:
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    handler = SnowflakeTableLogHandler(log_table_name, snowflake_session)
    handler.setLevel(level)
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(message)s'))
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger
```

This is called in stored procedures written in Snowpark, and all worked beautifully until recently, when this suddenly stopped logging INFO level messages.

While debugging this, I noticed that the logger level seemed to not get set properly, so I wrote the following test SP to isolate the problem, basically cutting out almost all my custom code to be able to focus on the logger level:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_logging()
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE PYTHON
  RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
  PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
  HANDLER = 'run'
AS
$$
import logging

def get_logger(name: str, level: int = logging.INFO) -> logging.Logger:
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    handler = logging.NullHandler()
    handler.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger


def run(session):
    return_strings = []
    logger = get_logger('hello', level=logging.DEBUG)
    return_strings.append(f'Logger level after creation: {logger.level}')
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    return_strings.append(f'Logger level after setting using setLevel: {logger.level}')
    logger.level = logging.INFO
    return_strings.append(f'Logger level after setting using .level: {logger.level}')
    return '\n'.join(return_strings)
$$;
```

Running this returns:

```
>>> call test_logging();
Logger level after creation: 0 
Logger level after setting using setLevel: 0 
Logger level after setting using .level: 20
```

What is going on here? Why is the setLevel method not working properly anymore? Though it's not insurmountable, this seems anything but obvious behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it "worked" previously but the behavior has changed the recommendation is to contact Snowflake Support.

---

For code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_logging()
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE PYTHON
  RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
  PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
  HANDLER = 'run'
AS
$$
import logging

def get_logger(name: str, level: int = logging.INFO) -> logging.Logger:
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    handler = logging.NullHandler()
    handler.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger


def run(session):
    return_strings = []
    logger = get_logger('hello', level=logging.DEBUG)
    return_strings.append(f'Logger level after creation: {logger.level}')
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    return_strings.append(f'Logger level after setting using setLevel: {logger.level}')
    logger.level = logging.INFO
    return_strings.append(f'Logger level after setting using .level: {logger.level}')
    return '\n'.join(return_strings)
$$;
```

Output:

```
SELECT CURRENT_VERSION();
-- 7.17.0

call test_logging();
-- Logger level after creation: 0
-- Logger level after setting using setLevel: 0
-- Logger level after setting using .level: 20
```

If we set up an event table as per [Logging and Tracing Overview](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/logging-tracing/logging-tracing-overview)

```
CREATE EVENT TABLE TEST_DB.TEST_SCHEMA.EVENT_TABLE;
ALTER ACCOUNT SET EVENT_TABLE = 'TEST_DB.TEST_SCHEMA.EVENT_TABLE';

-- ALTER ACCOUNT SET LOG_LEVEL = '...';
```

Output:

```
call test_logging();
-- Logger level after creation: 10
-- Logger level after setting using setLevel: 10
-- Logger level after setting using .level: 20
```

---

Related: [Logging Messages in Python](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/logging-tracing/logging-python)

> Before logging from code, you must:
>
> - **Set up an event table to collect messages logged from handler code.**
>
>   - For more information, refer to [Setting up an Event Table](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/logging-tracing/event-table-setting-up).
> - **Be sure you have the logging level set so that the messages you want are stored in the event table.**
>
>   - For more information, refer to [Setting Log Level](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/logging-tracing/logging-log-level).

Comment: That makes sense! Not sure I'm onboard with Snowflake's approach of silently disabling the setLevel method, but this works, thanks!

Comment: As part of adding the logging you mention, some of the standard methods were inadvertently disabled. This bug has been recorded and will be fixed with some other work (no date yet).